# How to generate test golden files from Integration test in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-test, flutter-integration-test

Is it possible to generate test golden files(images) when running an integration test in Flutter?

I'm able to generate the golden files when I run `flutter test --update-goldens` which happens not to run the integration test.

My main aim is being able to generate the test golden files(images) from an Android emulator when the integration test is running.
I tried running `flutter test integration_test/app_test.dart --update-goldens` but unfortunately, I got this error about having Read-only access permission:

[image]

Then I tried granting a READ and WRITE access permission using the `flutter driver`:

[image]

But unfortunately, Flutter driver skipped the process of generating or comparing the test golden file(image) when I run `flutter drive --driver=test_driver/integration_test.dart --target=integration_test/app_test.dart`:

[image]

The full source code is available [HERE](https://github.com/Joshuaerinosho/flutter_samples/tree/main/sample_app)

Comment: Goldens are a particularly great feature of the Flutter testing framework. But, what is the point if we cannot generate them on phones?

Comment: now seems that we no longer need `drive` but instead use `flutter test`

Answer (score 0):

The option above for `flutter test integration_test/app_test.dart --update-goldens`
now appears to work. I successfully ran it on a Windows project for a Windows Target.  I ran it in the Terminal Tab/Window of Android Studio Hedgehog.  I ran it from the project root and explicitly named my integration test file as shown above.  It generates the golden files and the failure folder in the integration_test folder.  I believe this question can be closed. DM me for deets.